# difference in else if {.. and else { if(

Tags: java, if-statement

I recently got coursework back and was award 0 marks for some stupid reason and I checked someone in my classes and this is my code:

```
 public static String take(String s, int n) {

  while(true){
      if(s.equals("")){
          return "";
      } else if(s.length() < n){
          return s;
      } else { 
          return s.substring(0,n);    
      }
```

but his is

```
public static String take(String s, int n) {
    while (true) {
        if (s.equals("")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            if (s.length() < n) {
                return s;
            } else {
                return s.substring(0, n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering is there a difference in

```
    else if{...}
```

and

```
    else{
          if{ }
    }
```

Our code does EXACTLY the same..

Comment: No, there is no difference with the code you've shown (you're missing a closing bracket though). Do note that you can't have two `else` statements.

Comment: Sorry, I'm extremely angry.. in my frustration I didn't think to correct that!

Comment: Also the `while(true)` is superfluous, you always return at the first iteration...

Comment: Yeah, it is pretty silly but there were told to do it that way!

Comment: `else if` is generally more in line with Java coding practice, but there are times when you may want the braces for emphasis.

Comment: @user Seriously! They want you to put a while (true){ } around **all** your methods. This is concerning

Comment: @RichardTingle At the time of this assignment it was what we had to do, I knew there was much better ways of doing such a thing but we had been introduce to recursion etc at the time

Comment: @user3259071: I have fixed the indentation on your post. This makes it clear that there could be a small difference. With the way it is now, you could make the case that the two last conditions might have to perform a common task which would then be placed in the first `else` block.

Comment: @user but the thing is it doesn't recurse. The while (true) could be removed and the code would behave exactly the same way

Comment: I have a an odd feeling that the entire point of this assignment was to introduce base cases and alternate cases before jumping headlong into recursion. That would explain the requirement of the single `else` to the base case. I can't possibly explain the `while(true)` but, again, we don't have the context of the entire assignment. Anyway, StackOverflow is really not a place for venting after a misunderstanding of the requirements. Wait until you reach the higher level courses and are expected to understand requirements from your barely English speaking database professor.

Comment: In my mind (as a programmer with 40 years experience) the first style is to be preferred.  There are cases, eg where there is some common computation that must be inserted, where the second style must be used, but it's uglier and harder to read.  The `while(true)` is bizarre.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no difference. You can do it either way.

Answer (score 2):

There is technically no difference, it's a matter of code style.

But keep in mind that in case of multiple `else if`, you may end up with a messy indentation :

```
if(test1) {
    ...
} else {
    if(test2) {
        ...
    } else {
        if(test3) {
            ...
        } else {
            if(test4) {
            ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

instead of the cleaner :

```
if(test1) {
    ...
} else if(test2) {
    ...
} else if(test3) {
    ...
} else if(test4) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference at all in its working. But, you can have multiple `else if` blocks consecutively, but not multiple `else` blocks consecutively with `if` inside it

Comment: That's a matter of correct nesting of braces ... you'd have to do `if {} else { if {} else {....} }`

Comment: @keshlam yes, absolutely .we can nest it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

You can do it in both ways.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In most cases I encourage people to use braces wherever they can; that is *never* to use:

```
 if(x) y = z;
```

and *always* to use:

```
 if(x) {
    y = z;
 }
```

However, "if else" is a solid idiom, so it's the exception to that rule:

```
 if(x) {
      ...
 } else if(y) {
      ...
 } else {
      ...
 }
```

... is well formatted code, and is equivalent to:

```
 if(x) {
      ...
 } else {
    if(y) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    } 
 }
```

... which is messier, and has scope for misplaced braces which change the logic.

Answer (score 0):

`else if` has no special meaning in Java.  It's an `else` part whose statement is an `if` statement; and one must take into account that since the `else` part is not a block enclosed in curly braces, the `else` part has only one statement.  So you could indent your example like this, to see it more clearly:

```
  if(s.equals("")){
      return "";
  } else 
      if(s.length() < n){
          return s;
      } else { 
          return s.substring(0,n);    
      }
```

while the other example looks like

```
    if (s.equals("")) {
        return "";
    } else {
        if (s.length() < n) {          // the second if statement starts here
            return s;
        } else {
            return s.substring(0, n);
        }                              // the second if statement ends here
    }
```

which is just the same, except for the extra braces around the second `if` statement.

But although `else if` is not special, as others have said, it's common enough that programmers follow different indentation and `{ }` conventions when using it, especially since sometimes there can be many of them chained together.  (In fact, in languages like Perl that don't allow `else if` without a curly brace after the `else`, or Ada which requires `end if` at the end of each `if`, the idiom is so indispensable that they added a special keyword `elsif` to allow programmers to use it.)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no difference technically but good practice to use else if {}